# Update the email address in the meteor user profile

Tags: meteor

I have created a user profile using simple schema and collection2.  If the name or email address is updated I want to update the meteor user profile.  When I try to set the email address in the meteor user profile it won't update.  This is the offending line:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {emails[0].address: pDetails.contactDetails.email}});
```

Can anyone show me how to update the meteor user profile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the array element based on the previous email address value in your selector.

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId(), 'emails.address': oldAddress },
 { $set: { 'emails.0.address': newAddress }});
```

You may have to set the `verified` field to false at the same time if the new email address is not verified. Then send the email verification email.

Comment: This doesn't work `"Unsupported projection option: $set: { emails.address: \"newemail@muydomain.com\" }"`

Comment: it should be emails.0.address

Comment: Thanks for that, very old answer!

Answer (score 1):

This also worked:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {'emails.0.address': pDetails.contactDetails.email, 'profile.name': pDetails.contactDetails.firstName}});
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, but only if there's only one email address in the array.

Comment: Yeah at the moment that's all there is.  Will do for now anyway, thank you for your help